# Buildout and Pythonbrew

Tags: python, linux, buildout

I am using Python 2.7.2 with Pythonbrew and I want to use buildout for some of my projects, that include some packages that need to be compiled with the C extensions.

However, when building it, it seems buildout cannot find the include folder located in `~/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/include`. If I try a simple `pip install simplejson`, then it works. So it seems buildout is looking in default include locations.

Is there a parameter config that I can set up in buildout for this?
Or an environment variable (I am under Centos 6.3)?

Related: [buildout - using different python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726289/buildout-using-different-python-version) but I prefer to keep my pythonbrew install as I may have different scenarii on other workstations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth (if it could help anyone), I could solve my problem by compiling Python with shared libraries with Pythonbrew.

```
pythonbrew install --configure="--enable-shared" 2.7.2
```